# Should I release an object if I add it to a subview but want to use it later?

Tags: ios, ipad, memory-management

Lets say that I have a `UIViewController` which has an instance variable `UIBarButtomItem *button` which is not a property. In `viewDidLoad` I do:

```
button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init...]
```

then

```
self.navigationController.leftBarButtonItem = button
```

Should I release the button object if I want to use it later in the same class? I have the same question about arrays (add an object to an array and use it later). I am confused because both the collections and `UIViews` retain the objects that are added to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you are accessing them later. If you are accessing them by instance variable and not by way of the target collection then you should definitely release them.

Comment: if button is an instance variable, then it should be released in viewDidUnload.

Answer (score 0):

_button = [UIBarButtonItem alloc] init ..] //assuming _button is class instance variable

button retain count is 1.

When you assign it to leftBarButtonItem property - its retain count becomes 2.

So as long you release the button object in your viewdidunload/dealloc, you should be good as when leftBarButton is gone or re-assigned it will make _button count to 0 and hence releasing your object correctly.

If _button is not an instance variable, then you should release _button and you can access to it again using .leftBarButtonProperty.

Comment: so if I release the button in viewDidUnload/dealloc, the navigation controller would release that button as well when it is removed from memory?